# Theme is not visible in admin panel

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm using the 1-click magento install from digitalocean. I downloaded a theme from templatemonster.com, added the sql database, and unzipped the theme file (fullpackage.zip) to "/app/design/frontend" as directed [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html). All the permissions are 770 or 775. I ran the magento command "setup:upgrade". My theme is not visible when I go to the themes section of the admin panel. Am I missing a step?

I also tried putting the theme file in several other places like /vendor/magento/.

I'm following [these](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-2-x-how-to-install-theme-using-fullpackage.html) setup instructions from templatemonster.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the theme contains the following folders/files please:

- `theme.xml`
- `registration.php`
- `media/preview.jpg`
- `web/css/source`
- `web/js`
- `web/images`
- `web/fonts`

If all those files exist then try the following:

- Clear Magento caches
- Log out of the admin and log back in

If it still doesn't display can you provide the contents of `registration.php` and `theme.xml` please.

Comment: was just about to write the same thing